# Prometheus: how to scrape with custom authentication

Tags: prometheus

I have a metrics endpoint that is protected by a custom authentication logic, in which the client must issue a POST request with username and password to get a temporary token in the response cookies, then add the token to the cookie in request header in the next request to access the metrics endpoint. I know Prometheus support basic auth, oauth2, authentication header. Is there a way to have Prometheus to execute the above custom authentication flow?